# How to get the current block number using Golang?

Tags: go-ethereum

It's a seemingly simple operation but I can't find an obvious way to do this using the `go-ethereum` library.

Given a blockchain client like so:

```
client, err := ethclient.Dial("http://localhost:8545")
```

The only available methods are:

```
BalanceAt
BlockByHash
BlockByNumber
CallContract
Close
CodeAt
EstimateGas
FilterLogs
HeaderByHash
HeaderByNumber
NetworkID
NonceAt
PendingBalanceAt
PendingCallContract
PendingCodeAt
PendingNonceAt
PendingStorageAt
PendingTransactionCount
SendTransaction
StorageAt
SubscribeFilterLogs
SubscribeNewHead
SuggestGasPrice
SyncProgress
TransactionByHash
TransactionCount
TransactionInBlock
TransactionReceipt
TransactionSender
```

Which does not include `GetBlockNumber` like it does in web3.js for example.

Comment: What do you mean by that @Jorropo

Comment: you usually do it by `eth.getBlock('latest')` or, `eth_getBlockByNumber('latest')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in a GitHub issue: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/15907

> You can retrieve the latest header with ethclient.HeaderByNumber(nil, nil), from which you can just pull the block number. The ethclient API is not meant to be a Go counterpart of the RPC spec (which is quite badly designed), rather an intuitive was to interface Ethereum from Go.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a full example of how to get the current (highest) block number using Go (from the [Ethereum Development with Go book](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-development-with-go-book)):

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    header, err := client.HeaderByNumber(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(header.Number.String()) // 5671744
}
```

Comment: Works great. Thx Miguel.